# WebDriverIO E2E tests - Alternatives to browser.pause()

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing

just raising this question for more experienced people with E2E tests.

I'm trying to figure out some alternatives to use in place of using `browser.pause(xxx)` for our tests.

One example we have is this:

I've tried adding a `waitUntilDisplayed` but it's not working, and obviously we have more where this happen, so I was hoping someone could give some insights of some good documentation about that to clarify my mind.

Thanks guys!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `waitForDisplayed()` instead of `waitUntilDisplayed()`.

Like this

```
element.waitForDisplayed();
expect(element).toBeExisting();
```

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed